# How to debug artifactory slowness?

Tags: artifactory

Installing PyPI or NPM packages from our company's Artifactory instance is about 5-10 times slower then installing from PyPI server or simple NFS share. The network infrastructure is the same in all cases and seems fine..

Does Artifactory suppose to be slower (Because extra security checks or something)?
How can I debug and fix the slowness?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be seeing such a difference between resolving from the public pypi/npm repositories and Artifactory.
There are a couple of things which may impact performance:

- Location of your Artifactory server - if your Artifactory server is located outside your network (for example if your client is on-prem and Artifactory is hosted in the cloud), make sure you have good network connection to Artifactory
- In case you are self hosting Artifactory - make sure that the resources provisioned to Artifactory are meeting the minimum [system requirements](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements). An overloaded database or a slow storage can affect download speed. In case your Artifactory is under a heavy load, you can take a look at some [tuning](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-tune-artifactory-for-heavy-loads/) best practices
- In case Artifactory is using LDAP/SAML for authentication, any latency in the communication with those will affect the download time. More information about debugging LDAP issues can be found in the [knowledge base](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/ldap-debugging-guide/)
- The type of repository you are resolving from can have an affect: if you are resolving from a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories), the connection to the remote URL can affect the download speed.
  You can get useful debug information by using the trace capability. Try downloading an artifact directly (using a browser or curl) and add the trace parameter, for example: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/npm-local/drorb/craftyjs-npm-example/-/drorb/craftyjs-npm-example-1.0.0.tgz?trace